# Angularjs/Javascript Odd Behavior "? string: ... ?"

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am loading data from a JSON object, including default values for select elements.  For example, one value is "16 %", and when I follow it through the code via log statements, it remains "16% " throughout.  That said, the select is not loaded correctly -- i.e., its blank.

When I run either `document.getElementById("tempPrimeResOwnerPerc*").value` or `angular.element(document.getElementById("tempPrimeResOwnerPerc*")).val()`, the response I get is "? string:16%  ?".  So far I have found nothing online about this, and would really appreciate some assistance.

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Im not quite sure how to go about that.  This is the behavior and Im wondering if anyone else has seen any cases.  If you point me toward them, I can research it...

Comment: I don't see a question. What are you doing and what do you want your code to do?

Comment: It has to do with how angular sets `value` from `ng-options` and that depends on how you construct the expression. You should never have to use a dom query to get that value...it is in your `ng-model` property

Comment: Cool!  Do you have any particular documentation/website you would look at?

Comment: Aleksey -- Its not so much a question over the code, its the behavior of subbing the strings out that Ive never seen before. Im just wondering if anyone has ever seen it (when I google it, I get nothing).  If you have seen it, where?

Comment: Use `ng-options` properly and you don't need to worry  what angular places in value of options. They are placeholders used to bind to `ng-model`. If you are using dom methods as shown that is a bad practice in angular app

Comment: I wish, but its not my code, so Im undoing...

Comment: Just get rid of the dom methods and use `ng-model` properly to access selected value(s). Without you showing relevant code hard for anyone to help more than that

Comment: And the documentation you need is in `ngOptions` and `ngModel` docs

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so this is a product of the generateUnknownOptionValue function (reproduced below).

```
self.generateUnknownOptionValue = function(val) {
  return '? ' + hashKey(val) + ' ?';
};
```

It has to do with Angularjs's strict compare of option values and the host DB converting the % sign to unicode....